# What's the name for the first line of a function?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology, nomenclature

I'm writing a worksheet, and want to ask students to write a function that looks like this:

```
isPrime(int number)
```

What's that line called - manifest comes to mind, but I don't think that's it...

Comment: It's probably a mistake to look for a language-agnostic answer here. Different languages have their own terminologies, for instance in C a function "declaration" and a function "signature" are not quite the same thing - the declaration is a concrete bit of code, that specifies the signature, which is a property of the function. So if the language you're actually using has its own jargon it's probably better to use that, rather than to use generic meanings which might conflict with language-specific meanings.

Comment: Good point - I'm specifically thinking of Python, but C is the language I was formally taught.

Comment: In Python I'd call it a function signature. Python doesn't need declarations, and I think bringing in a C term would confuse things more than it explains them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be called `header`, `declaration` or `signature`.

The first one would go well with "function declaration", "function header", "function body".

Comment: you might also add a return type to the function declaration

Comment: Signature was what I was thinking of, declaration sounds good as well!

Comment: Signature was by @skaffman, +1 him up somewhere if you like it :P

Answer (score 4):

`function prototype`,`declaration` or `signature`

Answer (score 4):

If you write

```
bool isPrime(int);
```

you call this *declaration* whereas

```
bool isPrime(int number) { /* code */ }
```

is the actual *definition*. (C allows a explicit distinction here)

Generally, your expression is called the (type) *signature* of a function.

Comment: Doesn't "definition" include the body?

Answer (score -1):

Signature == name, number of parameters, type of parameters, but NOT the return type, whereas declaration == signature + return type